# Python: User's input defining file extension

Tags: python, tkinter, file-extension

I need to code a tkinter dialog box, where user must input **three letters only** (file extension). I'm using my code to ask user for two different types of files within some folder, but there are files with lowercase and uppercase extension, therefore I need to transform the result into **uppercase and lowercase** string.

Here is my code:

```
class ext_box(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    def body(self, master):
        Label(master, text="First file extension:").grid(row=0)
        Label(master, text="Second file extension:").grid(row=1)
        self.e1 = Entry(master)
        self.e2 = Entry(master)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        return self.e1
    def validate(self):
        try:
            ext1 = ?
            ext2 = ?
            self.result = ext1, ext2
            return 1
        except ValueError:
            tkMessageBox.showwarning(
                "Please try again."
            )
            return 0
```

**Edit:**

This code works with *ext1 = self.e1.get()* and *ext1 = self.e2.get()*.

My questions are:

How can I define three letters as an input from the user for ext1 and ext2? After I get these results, How can I make the input uppercase and lowercase for each result?

Comment: What your real question then?

Comment: @piglei How can I define three letters as an input from the user for `ext1` and `ext2`? After I get these results, How can I make the input uppercase and lowercase for each result?

Answer (score 1):

Is your question how to transform a string to uppercase or lowercase? In that case you can use string.upper() or string.lower()

example:

```
>>> 'a'.upper()
'A'
>>> 'A'.lower()
'a'
```

Comment: How can I tranform the results (in this case `ext1` and `ext2`) into lowercase and uppercase version. For example user inputs `jpg` and `txt`. But I want Python to search for `jpg` and `JPG` files as well as `TXT` and `txt` files. If I leave it, script will search for defined extension by user - in that case the user can input even `Txt` or `TxT` and because Python is case sensitive it will look for these extensions only.

Answer (score 0):

In order to extract the current values from the `Entry` items you need something like:

```
ext1 = self.e1.get()
ext2 = self.e2.get()
```

but that's unlikely to raise a `ValueError`, you will need further validation code to that. Suitable validation code might look something like this.

```
if (len(ext1) != 3 or not ext1.isalpha()
        or len(ext2) != 3 or not ext1.isalpha()):
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: I know, but shouldn't be there something like `ext1 = str(self.e1.get())` and `ext1 = str(self.e2.get())` to validate letters? Through this bit I would like to validate three letters only. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: The `str` function converts to strings, without applying any validation. I have altered my answer to include limited validation (each extension must be 3 characters long and alphabetic), but you may need to add more depending on your upper/lower-case requirements. Or, if they validate correctly, you may just want to convert them to upper case.

Also, since the validation routine appears to return only `True` or `False` it can be simplified so it doesn't use exceptions at all.

Comment: The user can enter lowercase and uppercase letters - I just want the three letters rule there. The result will be **then** (below the code I posted) transformed to uppecase and lowercase strings (so there will be two results for both extensions).

Comment: The code itself works with `ext1 = self.e1.get()` and `ext1 = self.e2.get()`